# Does redeclaring a cursor create new connection while using psycopg2?

Tags: linux, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2, amazon-redshift

I am using the *psycopg2* library with *Python3* on a linux server to create some temporary tables on Redshift and querying these tables to get results and write to files on the server.

1. Since my queries are long and takes about 15 minutes to create all these temp tables that I ultimate pull data from, how do I ensure that my connection persists and I don't lose the temp tables that I later query? Right now I just do a cursor() before the execute(), is there a default timeout for these?
2. I have noticed that whenever I do a

> Select a,b from #results_table

or

> select * from #results_table

the query just freezes/hangs, but

> select top 35 from #results_table

returns the results (select top 40 fails!). There are about a 100 rows in #results_table, and I am not able to get them all. I did a `ps aux` and the process just stays in the S+ state. If I manually run the query on Redshift it finishes in seconds.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-declaring a cursor doesn't create new connection while using psycopg2.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out there was an issue with how the server was tunneled by Amazon. A change was made to the MTU on the network interface and queries ran fine after that.